# Custom validation attribute not working after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validationattribute

Recently I been hand on a MVC project, and I required to make an custom validation attribute for certain model,

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TimeGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public TimeGreaterThanAttribute(string timeToCompareToFieldName, string dayOff)
    {
        TimeToCompareToFieldName = timeToCompareToFieldName;
        DayOff = dayOff;
    }

    private string TimeToCompareToFieldName { get; set; }
    private string DayOff { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ... 
    }
}

public class ScreenConfigViewModel
{
    public bool WholeDayOff { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    [TimeGreaterThan("StartTime", "WholeDayOff")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Something like the example shown above, and I tested locally, it works pretty well, and no problem at all.

**Problem**

But once I publish and deploy to working server, the custom validation fail to work, it doesn't validate the value, doesn't throw any error message. And I can't figure out why.

Because of different environment, I assumed it has configuration on it? Where require to enable custom validation attribute in order for it to work. But I can't figure out where and what the configuration is.

Anyone know whats problem occurs on? or it doesn't have such configuration and just my code having problem.

***Sorry for not providing sufficient codes, just trying to know whether is configuration issues or coding issues***

Sorry if I explain the situation badly.
Any help to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the new environment in a different time zone, or configured with a different culture?

Comment: @JohnWu the environment is configured same time zone same culture as my local be

Comment: It could be a deployment issue. Perhaps a missing js file or web.config setting? Is there other validation that is working?

Comment: Show your code for the `IsValid()` method

Answer (score 0):

Please check if on Published environment below 2 dll are published succesfully or not 
`Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly

The reason may be due to missing dlls on your environment.

Let me know if solution worked for you.

Comment: OP code would not even run if the dll's were missing.